# Exception (500 internal server error) by call web service (Endpoint without extension .asmx)

Tags: vb.net

every one, i just wanna get a response from a web Service (Endpoint http: //XXX/XXX/xxxxxxport1, without extension .asmx).

I tried this with SOAPUI, and it worked fine. But when i tried call this with a vb.net Program, i got this exception (500 internal server error).

I think my vb.net code is fine, because i used the same code to call other web service, no problem at all. (for example, i tried this with "http: //www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx", "http: //www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx", "http: //www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx" ).

my code:

Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://XXX/XXX/xxxxxxport1")

```
        Dim proxy As IWebProxy = CType(myReq.Proxy, IWebProxy)
        Dim proxyaddress As String
        Dim myProxy As New WebProxy
        Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding
        Dim buffer() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(xml.ToString)
        Dim response As String

        myReq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = False
        myReq.Timeout = 10000
        myReq.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        myReq.AuthenticationLevel = Security.AuthenticationLevel.None
        myReq.Method = "POST"
        myReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
        myReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length

        myReq.PreAuthenticate = True
        proxyaddress = proxy.GetProxy(myReq.RequestUri).ToString

        Dim newUri As New Uri(proxyaddress)
        myProxy.Address = newUri
        myReq.Proxy = myProxy
        Dim post As Stream = myReq.GetRequestStream

        post.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        post.Close()


        Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse

        Dim responsedata As Stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream
        Dim responsereader As New StreamReader(responsedata)

        response = responsereader.ReadToEnd
```

Any one know this? should i do something different by call a endpoint without .asmx, or?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you able to access the remote server? What does it say in the IIS or event logs on what the error was? This is a server side (services) issue. Generally speaking when you are posting data and you get a 500 error on the server side - its to do with the data you are sending

Comment: With SoapUI i can access the remote, and get a correct response, a xml file. Somehow not work with vb.net

Comment: I sent the same request-data, I have checked so many times.  :-(

Comment: no, not with SOAPUI - are you able to access to the server which hosts the web service? (RDP session?)

Comment: ty for help, i dont have the access, but i will ask for it.